# Retrieve a list of services running on a server vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, wmi, wmi-query

I'm looking for a way to get details of the name and status of all services running on a service. I did use the following code:

```
    Public Sub GetServices()
    Dim localServices As ServiceController() = ServiceController.GetServices()
    For Each service As ServiceController In localServices
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(service.DisplayName) Then
            dictservice(service.DisplayName) = New Service(service.DisplayName, service.ServiceName, service.Status.ToString)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

However, since i have packaged up my project as a WCF service, the System.ServiceProcess namespace i used cannot be used:[image: System.ServiceProcess]

Is there any other way i can retrieve the same details? Possibly through wmi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that message is saying is that, when trying to import the namespace, either there was nothing in it, or it wasn't found.

Usually this is just a case of a missing reference, are you sure you've added a reference to System.ServiceProcess in your project?